# I want to convert multiple characters to Python regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to convert only numbers in this str

```
"ABC234TSY65234525erQ"
```

I tried to change only areas with numbers to the * sign

This is what I wanted

```
"ABC*TSY*erQ"
```

But when I actually did it, it came out like this

```
"ABC***TSY********erQ"
```

How do I change it?

Thanks you!

Comment: Does it mean you used `\d` and not `\d+`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `\d+`. `+` in a regular expression means "match the preceding character one or more times"

```
import re
s = re.sub(r'\d+', '*', s)
```

output:

```
'ABC*TSY*erQ'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `re.sub()` solution given by @JayPeerachi is probably the best option, but we could also use `re.findall()` here:

```py
inp = "ABC234TSY65234525erQ"
output = '*'.join(re.findall(r'\D+', inp))
print(output)  # ABC*TSY*erQ
```